# Entity Framework only saving some of my fields

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to write a small web api and it is my first time using entity framework.

My problem is that only some of my data gets saved.

I have this GET method which is just supposed to save a model into the database:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> PopulateDB()
{
    var playerOneQuest = new StatusModel
    {
        PlayerId = "1",
        points= 250,
        completedSteps = new List<Status>()
        {
            new Status
            {
                Id = 11,
                Index = 1
            } 
        }
    };
    
    _context.Quest.Add(playerOneQuest);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok("Added data"); // Breakpoint here
}
```

When I add a breakpoint at the last line `_context` looks perfectly fine with all the data, but as soon as the method has executed `completedSteps` will be null. The other data - `PlayerId` & `points` - are saved just fine.

I have tried adding this `_context.Entry(playerOneQuest).State = EntityState.Added;` before calling `SaveChangesAsync()`, but `completedSteps` still ends up null after the method has executed.

`_context` is defined as:

```
public class QuestContext : DbContext
{
    public QuestContext(DbContextOptions<QuestContext> options)
        : base(options){  }

    public virtual DbSet<StatusModel> Quest { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

The 2 models used are defined as:

```
public class StatusModel
{
    [Key]
    public string? PlayerId {get;set;}
    public long Points{get;set;}
    public List<Status> completedSteps {get;set;} = null!;
}

public class Status
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public int Index {get;set;}
}
```

And for good measure, this is how the database context is added to my web app:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<QuestContext>(opt =>
opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("Quests"));
```

Comment: Did you try adding public virtual DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }  to QuestContext?

Comment: @sam yes I did try that. It had no effect so I removed it again

Comment: Actually Status is required to be added to context. Per EF navigation rules, if you define/add child entities to context then parent will be resolved by EF itself. So, I would add Status and having StatusModel is not mandatory in this scenario we are discussing. Could you please edit your question to just show us the part how the navigation is defined in your  StatusModel and Status entities/objects?

Comment: How do your Status and StatusModel entities look like? Did you set up the navigation properties, foreign keys etc? How are PKs are defined - can you really set the IDs or are they DB generated?

Comment: @Sam I did read something along those lines before, but I don't know I'd add "StatusModel" to the database if the context is defined with "Status"

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh I defined one key attribute, honestly do not know how to do any of the other things you mentioned within Entity framework. I've added the data models to make things more clear

Comment: How about to test on SQLite? In-memory storage just for testing and probably has it's own bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't specify that you want to load additional data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

You can either enable lazy loading via proxies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy or be explicit by using the `.Include()` on the query.

`var completeList = await _questContext.Quest.Include(i => i.completedSteps).ToListAsync();`

Your entities are correctly setup by following the conventions as far  as I can tell. This means that you don't need to configure anything additional regarding the entities - when you just want to have a simple one-to-many relationship.

Example on a controller where the `QuestContext` is injected:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly QuestContext _questContext;

    public MyController(QuestContext questContext)
    {
        _questContext = questContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<NoContentResult> Get()
    {
        var playerOneQuest = new StatusModel
        {
            PlayerId = "1",
            Points = 250,
            completedSteps = new List<Status>()
            {
                new Status
                {
                    Id = 11,
                    Index = 1
                }
            }
        };

        _questContext.Quest.Add(playerOneQuest);
        await _questContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpGet("check")]
    public async Task<List<StatusModel>> Check()
    {
        var completeList = await _questContext.Quest.Include(i => i.completedSteps).ToListAsync();
        return completeList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems great, nice and simple. My only 2 issues are: 1. that the examples from MS uses "using (var context = new BloggingContext())" and my context is injected with an  DbContextOptions argument, so I don't know how to do that... and 2. calling my _context.Quest normally has no ".Include()" on it.
So I really wish you are right, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a controller where the `QuestContext`  is injected into the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. That is literally what I already have in my code. _questContext.Quest just does not have .Include() on it. I have no idea what to change to get fix that

Comment: What do you mean? It's not there on the Quest object??

Comment: Are you having this using? `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: As my actual project is a bit more complicated than my question I did finally find a file that did not have  `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`. Now it all works!

Answer (score 1):

In models:

```
 public class StatusModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id {get;set;}
        public long Points{get;set;}
        public List<Status> completedSteps {get;set;} = new List<Status>();
    }
    
    public class Status
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id {get;set;}
        public int Index {get;set;}
        public long StatusModelId {get;set;}
        public StatusModel {get;set;}
    }
```

In your storage context in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Status>().HasOne(c => c.StatusModel).WithMany(c => c.completedSteps)
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.StatusModelId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

You have to set up the relations between objects. You can do it in your Context with fluent API, or with attributes directly in the models. Also in your context you need both DbSets, for status and for statusModel.

Wrote the answer without testing, should be close enough though. Here is a link to relations: [Relations in EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

I missed your PlayerId - this is I guess an FK to Player? Than you have to set up that relation as well. If you intended it as PK, it probably should not be nullable.

Comment: From what I've read elsewhere, and also in your link, all these extra steps should not be needed.
I have tried following all your advice and the only thing that made a change was "new List<Status>();" This resulted in "completedSteps" being an empty list every time, rather than simply null